# Count sublists with the same values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, counter

How to count sublists with the same values (order doesn't matter) in a list?

I tried this:

```py
from collections import Counter

Input = [
    [
        'Test123', 'heyhey123', 'another_unique_value',
    ],
    [
        'Test123', 'heyhey123', 'another_unique_value',
    ],
    [
        'heyhey123',
    ],
    [
        'Test123', 'heyhey123',
    ],
    [
        'another_unique_value', 'heyhey123', 'Test123'
    ]
]

Counter(str(e) for e in li)

Output:

Counter({
    "['Test123', 'heyhey123', 'another_unique_value']": 2},
    "['heyhey123']": 1},
    "['Test123', 'heyhey123']": 1},
    "['another_unique_value', 'heyhey123', 'Test123']": 1},
)
```

Obviously it takes the order from the values in the list in account. How do I count the sublists where the order doesn't matter?

The output I want is:

```py
Counter({
    "['Test123', 'heyhey123', 'another_unique_value']": 3},
    "['heyhey123']": 1},
    "['Test123', 'heyhey123']": 1},
)
```

Comment: Use `set(e)` instead of `str(e)`

Comment: @Barmar you'd have to use `tuple(set(e))` - sets are unhashable.

Comment: Alternatively, if values can occur twice in one sublist, you could use `tuple(sorted(e))`.

Comment: @CDJB Bingo!. `tuple(set(e))` probably wouldn't work because the order of set elements isn't defined.

Comment: @CDJB That did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

```
Counter(str(e) for e in li)
```

with

```
Counter(tuple(sorted(e)) for e in li)
```

Giving output:

```
Counter({('Test123', 'another_unique_value', 'heyhey123'): 3,
         ('heyhey123',): 1,
         ('Test123', 'heyhey123'): 1})
```

Another option would be to use `set(e)` to ignore the order of elements in the list, but this has the downside of ignoring repetitions - `['Test123', 'heyhey123', 'another_unique_value']` would be counted as the same as `['Test123', 'heyhey123', 'another_unique_value', 'another_unique_value']` - and in addition, when converting from the unhashable `set` to include in a `Counter`, an identical order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close.

`Counter(str(set(e)) for e  in Input)`
returns

```
Counter({"{'heyhey123', 'Test123', 'another_unique_value'}": 3,
     "{'heyhey123'}": 1,
     "{'heyhey123', 'Test123'}": 1})
```

which is almost identical to what you're looking for I believe :)